# Count real website load speed via proxy?

Tags: php, proxy, load

i make code for measure load speed of website but don't know if is possible measure real load speed of website via some proxy i try but always give me some abnormal number because slowness of proxy, there is some solution for measure real website load speed via proxy  ?

Comment: Give us some more info first. What are you using to measure the load speed of a website? What have you tried to fix this?

Comment: i need way how to measure real website load speed via some proxy e.g. 181.88.177.145 this is argentina proxy when i try measure load speed i get 19sec this is not real website load speed, now how i can know how much is this proxy slower and get real website load from some country depend of proxy location ?

Comment: Open proxies are used and misused by all kind of people to all kind of purposes, they are considered a security issue to whoever is running them and you cannot expect to have consistent results when tunneling your traffic through a compromised server. It can aswell be running in some home computer with a 1Mbps link and 20 people trying to download garbage through it, it won't perform consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Use **curl_getinfo** method after execute

```
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
        $head = curl_exec($ch); 
        $proxy_time = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME); 
        curl_close($ch);
```

- CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME
- CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME
- CURLINFO_STARTTRANSFER_TIME
- CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT
- CURLINFO_REDIRECT_TIME

More information you can see here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Good luck!